# Referring to other JavaScript file in controller.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an AngularJS Singple Page Application with a controller.js file configured in it. At certain moments in the application, I'm making database-calls. To convert the retrieved XML to JSON, I make use of an external .js which is part of an API named x2js.

I want to refer to this external JavaScript file inside my controller, so I can call the functions of the JavaScript class. Referring to the file in the main index.html-file doesn't work for some reason... Any idea how I can refer to an external .js-file inside my controller?

Mayby worth mentioning, but I'm using typescript files instead of regular JavaScript-files... Don't know if that changes the situation?

I made a pastebin of the external .js-file (x2js.js, this is not typescript):
http://pastebin.com/p80Akp6s

When I'm calling following statement in controller.ts:

```
 var xml2jsonConverter = new x2js({ arrayAccessForm: "property" });
```

It gives an error syntax highlight, stating that the specified parameters aren't valid. However, when I'm adding this code between `<script>`-tags inside the index.html, it doesn't give any error-indication and it compiles just fine.

Here you can see my index.html-page. I insert the controller AND the external .js. Calling it from the script-tags works just fine.
http://pastebin.com/WpXZRSZV

The controller.ts is rather big, and I'm doing nothing other than calling:

```
var xml2jsonConverter = new X2JS({ arrayAccessForm: "property" });
```

The error messages I'm getting are:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

and

```
Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword
```

Comment: Please provide a small example illustrating your problem. Normally you would include the js file in index and then call the code from the controller

Comment: I added extra code and information to my main post ;) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show a block of code where you include js files and file with controller.

Comment: Include xml2json.min.js before angular application. Include angular.js before your controllers and directives. It should be similar to this: cordova.js, xml2json.min.js, angular.js and then angular controllers, dirictives and other angular files.

Comment: Nope that didn't work... the error is not during compilation and changing the lines in the index.html did nothing... But you were right about the order of declaring the scripts.

Comment: The strange thing is that some other methods do work. It's just the initialisation with the parameter that doesn't work when using the script in controller.ts.

Comment: Perhaps your controller wrapped in an anonymous function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77939/discussion-between-ivanmalenko-and-cedriccornelis).

Answer (score 0):

use $window

```
//outside of angular
function functionName() {
    var num = 0
}

//inside controller
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('mainController',function ($scope,$window) {
    $scope.number = $window.num
})
```